# API for SOLR cache Statistics

Tags: solr

Is there an API to view SOLR cache statistics like we have for core admin?

`/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS&core=core1`

SOLR version: 4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the URL that worked for me -

```
http://<solrhost>:<solrport>/solr/<CORE NAME>/admin/mbeans?action=STATUS&stats=true&cat=CACHE
```